# 64-bit Steam version of Banished crashes on launch

Tags: steam, technical-issues, banished

Launching the 64-bit exe of the game (through Steam) gives crashes and writes a dump with the following:

```
Process Name             Application-steam-x64.exe
Process Architecture     x64
Exception Code           0xC0000005
Exception Information    The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information         Not Present
```

The 32-bit executable works fine, but that is not the one that Steam launches, so launching it is a bit inconvenient. Running the 64-bit version as administrator does not help, nor does compatibility mode. I'm using Windows 8.1 x64 Pro, AMD processor and NVIDIA GTX 780.

Is there some other workaround to this than using the 32-bit version?

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit system?

Comment: @SaintWacko Yes.

Comment: ...Was that bit in the question body about your computer there, and I just overlooked it?

Comment: @SaintWacko Pretty much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As of **version 1.0.1**](http://www.shiningrocksoftware.com/2014-02-27-working-on-an-update/) you can use the command-line parameter `/dx9` to force the game to DirectX 9.0c mode and fix the crash.

### Using the command-line parameter

#### All versions

- Create a shortcut for Banished 64-bit executable (Application-steam-x64.exe for Steam version)
- Edit the shortcut properties and add `/dx9` to the end of the "Target" field:

> [image: Target: mmon/Banished/Application-steam-x64.exe /dx9]

#### Steam only

- Banished > Properties > Set launch options
- Add `/dx9` to the field shown:

[image: Banished - Properties - Set launch options... - /dx9]

### Notes

- This does not save the setting and will only use it as long as the parameter is present. Removing the parameter will revert to the default setting (which *can* be the same!)
- Similarly, you can use `/dx11` to force the game to use DirectX 11.

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same issue. Crash dump looks like it's dying starting up DX11 - you can force the game into DX9 mode with some registry editing, if you're comfortable with that. (regedit.exe)

If you navigate to, (or you might have to add)
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Shining Rock Software LLC\Banished`

Then add a new **string** value (not integer!)

```
name: VideoInterface 
value: 0
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: If you're not a techy, you can just [download this registry file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2510538/banished-fix.reg) and import it to your registry. It will apply the fix as described by Andew.

Answer (score 2):

Go into `Program Files (x86)/Steam/...SteamApps/common/Banished`

and cut the files VideoDX11-steam-x64.dll and VideoDX11-steam-x32.dll into a new folder. Game started perfectly after that for me!